# tar (on Windows) a list of files in c#

Tags: c#, windows, process, gzip, tar

I then to tar and then gzip a list of files in C#.

I need some help with how to set the arguments to tar.

Say I have tar.exe in a folder c:\tar\tar.exe and a method like the following:

```
    private void RunTar(string outputFileName, List<string> fileNamePaths)
    {
        using (Process p = new Process())
        {
            p.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\tar\tar.exe";
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = //;
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
```

**Note: the fileNamePathsToTar list has the full unc filename paths and the files can be in different folders.**

Can anyone please help with what **arguments** to supply.

Also I notice in the documentation:

```
-z, --gzip, --ungzip
          filter the archive through gzip

   -Z, --compress, --uncompress
          filter the archive through compress

   --use-compress-program=PROG
          filter through PROG (must accept -d)
```

Not sure how to use this but if I place the gzip.exe in the same folder as tar.exe **can I perform my tar and then gzip of these files all in one step**?

**Update**

I can only seem to get tar to work on files in the same directory as tar.exe if I try a full path name I get something like:

```
    C:\Tar Test>tar -cf out.tar c:/Tar Test/Text/t1.txt
tar: Cannot add file c:/Tar: No such file or directory
tar: Cannot add file Test/Text/t1.txt: No such file or directory
tar: Error exit delayed from previous errors
```

I've tried with the slashes both ways \ or / and with quotes around the full path no joy.

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest asking this w/o Process on SuperUser.

Comment: try this way

C:\Tar Test>tar -cf out.tar "c:/Tar Test/Text/t1.txt"

Comment: Hey that works C:\Tar Test>tar -cf out.tar "c:/Tar Test/Text/t1.txt"
What doesn't work is C:\Tar Test>tar -cf "c:/out.tar" "c:/Tar Test/Text/t1.txt". So I can read a file from a full path but not output to any location only locally.

Comment: Also I can only get this to work for 1 file, I want to be able to provide a list of files any idea the format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to create an archive and gzip it, you should use czf as arguments, so

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "czf";
```

or

```
p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-czf";
```

depending on tar version.

to avoid gzipping, remove the 'z' from the arguments.

ah, and you'd better tar an entire folder, like put all your file in a folder named, e.g., myfolder and tar that folder, not it's content.

Comment: -cvf works but when I try czf I get: 

C:\Tar Test>tar -czf out.tar t1.txt
tar: Cannot fork: Function not implemented
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: try out.tar.gz, not just out.tar

Comment: Actually different error now cannot fork. C:\Tar Test>tar -czf out.tar.gz "c:/Tar Test/Text/t1.txt"
tar: Cannot fork: Function not implemented
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Because tar only supports unix like path. Another solution is to 'cd' to that directory and run with relative path.

Answer (score 0):

FYI, there's a managed tar library with full source available at 
http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/srcview.aspx?dir=Tar&file=Tar.cs

There's a makefile to allow you to build Tar.dll or Tar.exe.  There's also a sample app in VB.